# Getting "A node reference could not be resolved' error while testing safari

Tags: safari, nightwatch

I am testing an app in Safari. I can login to the app then I need to make a choice by clicking an element but clicking does not happen and I am getting this error:

√ Element <aside[aria-label='Ancillary/Correlative Studies']> was visible after 6 milliseconds.
Error while running .executeScript() protocol action: A node reference could not be resolved: Node with identifier 'node-05E2144A-31BF-42F7-B950-CA736A981283' was not found

Here is my configuration related with safari:
`safari: { dataDir: __dirname + '/downloads', desiredCapabilities: { browserName: "safari", javascriptEnabled: true, elementScrollBehavior: 1, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, options: { cleanSession: true } }, webdriver: { use_legacy_jsonwire: false, start_process: true, port: getPort(), server_path: '/usr/bin/safaridriver' } } }`

only changed  use_legacy_jsonwire to true but test did not start at all